# EF4.1 and Left Outer Join to find nulls?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, outer-join

I have two tables, Address & People.  People has FK to Address. I'm trying to find addresses where there are no people:

```
select id from Address a 
left outer join person p on p.address_id = a.id
where p.address_id is null
```

Is this possible using LINQ to Entities? I tried a few variations around

```
 var results = from addr in _context.Addresses
               from ppl in addr.People
               where ppl == null ...
```

but can't seem to figure out how to return addresses where there are no people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose:

```cs
var results = (from addr in _context.Addresses
               where !addr.People.Any()
               select addr).ToList();
```